# Windows: Utility to see details of laptop battery

Tags: windows, battery

Is there is an utility that will show me detailed information on my laptop battery on Windows? Details could be type, make, capacity, current charge, number of discharge cycles, and other SMART-like details if they are available.

Something like CPU-Z, but for batteries :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use [BatteryCare](http://batterycare.net), it does all the items you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, (and possibly earlier editions) there is a really handy built in tool. After running this report yesterday, I realized that my battery capacity was only 70% of its design capacity and was able to get a new battery under warranty.

[image: Screenshot of report]

From a command prompt:

```
powercfg /batteryreport /output "battery_report.html"
```

Or a one-liner which opens the report in your default browser:

```
powercfg /batteryreport /output "%userprofile%\battery_report.html" && "%userprofile%\battery_report.html"
```